# Ask to ffmpeg to wait the reconnection of rtp source

Tags: ffmpeg, connection, rtp

I used this command to change the streaming parameters :

```
ffmpeg -i rtp://192.168.0.12:1234 -timeout -1 -shortest -ac 2 -ar 16000 -acodec pcm_s16le -f rtp rtp://192.168.0.12:4567
```

This is work well, ffmpeg wait the connection of the source to start.

But i don't found the options to indicate at ffmpeg to wait the reconnection of the source if the connection has been cuted.

Somebody know if this option exist ?
Thank's in adavance.

Comment: I try to different way to resolve my problem without success :
1) - find an option to ask at ffmpeg "don't stop even if the input source is cuted.
2) - when the input source is cuted, ffmpeg stop his process after 2 or 3 scs : find an option to ask at ffmpeg "if the input source is cuted, stop your process immediately"xs

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
-stimeout 1000000
```

command in before input parameter